# Yarn 4 sharing dependencies between packages in monorepo

Tags: dependencies, yarnpkg, monorepo, yarn-v4

I have a monorepo that has a package `packages/my-config` containing babel configuration and all the required dependencies for that configuration.

When I was using yarn 1 when I imported that configuration into `packages/my-app`, all I had to include in `package.json` was `my-config` package, and it would resolve all it's dependencies correctly. So for example I didn't have to have `@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import` inside `packages/my-app`, it worked.

After I upgraded to yarn 4, it no longer works that way, now I have to specify all of the packages that are used by the configuration in both `packages/my-app` and `packages/my-config`. It doesn't seem like the expected behavior. How can I make it work like before?